# crashing fallout shelter

Tags: technical-issues, fallout-shelter

I was on a Paula Plumbkin quest when 1 enemy died but kept shooting and wouldn't stop killing my people, so I removed the app from the background and from then on every time I press enter vault it just crashes. I haven't been able to enter since. I have tried restarting my device to no avail I am using an iPhone 5

Comment: Can you make a new vault?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of several ways to fix this issue:

- Contact fallout shelter's support team, and they may be able to help you.
- Delete the app, and re-install it.  You may be lucky enough to get the app's data back. (Not guaranteed! You may lose all of your vaults and data!)
- If you don't care about that vault, just make a new one, and say bye to the one that crashes you.
- Wait for an update of the app that may fix the bug. (A waste of time.)